# To-Do-List project

Tags: python-3.7

need help in following project where two classes Task and To-Do-List.

I am getting following errors. Trying to resolve but still coming up

> Enter an option3
>   Enter a task:hello
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/Users/vrishabpatel/Desktop/dominos/pythonExamples/toDoList/menu.py", line 75, in 
>      Menu().run()
>    File "/Users/vrishabpatel/Desktop/dominos/pythonExamples/toDoList/menu.py", line 43, in run
>      action()
>    File "/Users/vrishabpatel/Desktop/dominos/pythonExamples/toDoList/menu.py", line 60, in add_tasks
>      self.toDoList.new_task(task_name, complete="N")
>    File "/Users/vrishabpatel/Desktop/dominos/pythonExamples/toDoList/toDoList.py", line 37, in new_task
>      self.tasks.append(Task(task_name, complete))
>   AttributeError: 'ToDoList' object has no attribute 'tasks'

```
from datetime import datetime


"""To Do List Programe"""
"""Represent a Tasks in the To-DoList. 
match against a string in searches and store each
tasks"""
last_id = 0


class Task:
    def __init__(self, task_name, complete=""):
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.complete = "N"
        self.date_created = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y')
        global last_id
        last_id += 1
        self.id = last_id

    def match_task(self, filter):
        """Determine if this note matches the filter
        text. Return True if it matches, False otherwise.
        Search is not case sensitive and matches any word in the tasks. """

        return filter.lower() in self.task_name.lower()


class ToDoList:
    """Represent a collection of tasks that 
    can be searched, modified and complete and deleted """

    def __int__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    def new_task(self, task_name, complete):
        """Create new task and add it to the list"""
        self.tasks.append(Task(task_name, complete))

    def _find_task(self, task_id):
        """locate the task with given id"""
        for task_name in self.tasks:
            if str(task_name.id) == str(task_name.id):
                return task_name
        return None

    def modify_task(self, task_id, task_name):
        task_name = self._find_task(task_id)
        if task_name:
            task_name.task_name = task_name
            return True
        return False

    def delete_task(self, task_id, complete):
        task = self._find_task(task_id)
        if task:
            task.complete = "Y"
            return self.tasks.remove(task_id-1)
        return False

    def search(self, filter):
        """Find all task that match the given 
        fliter string """
        return [task for task in self.tasks if task.match(filter)]
```

And Menu class as follows...

```
"""Main File to Run the programe"""
import sys
from toDoList import ToDoList


class Menu:
    """Display a menu and respond to choices when
    run """

    def __init__(self):
        self.toDoList = ToDoList()
        self.choices = {
            "1": self.show_tasks,
            "2": self.search_tasks,
            "3": self.add_tasks,
            "4": self.delete_tasks,
            "5": self.quit,
        }

    def display_menu(self):
        print(
            """
            To Do List menu
            ===============

            1. Show all Tasks 
            2. Search Tasks
            3. Add Tasks
            4. Delete Tasks
            5. Quit

            """

        )

    def run(self):
        """Display the menu and repond to the choices"""
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            choice = input("Enter an option")
            action = self.choices.get(choice)
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("{0} is not a valid choice".format(choice))

    def show_tasks(self, tasks=None):
        if not tasks:
            tasks = self.toDoList.tasks
        for task in tasks:
            print("{0}: {1}".format(task.id, task))

    def search_tasks(self):
        filter = input("Search tasks:")
        tasks = self.toDoList.search(filter)
        self.show_tasks(tasks)

    def add_tasks(self):
        task_name = input("Enter a task:")
        self.toDoList.new_task(task_name, complete="N")
        print("Your task has been added:")

    def delete_tasks(self):
        id = input("Enter a task id:")
        task = input("Enter task name:")
        if task:
            self.toDoList.delete_task(id, task)

    def quit(self):
        print("Thank you for using To-Do-List today")
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Menu().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your class definition

```
class ToDoList:
    """Represent a collection of tasks that 
    can be searched, modified and complete and deleted """

    def __int__(self):
        self.tasks = []
```

should be

```
class ToDoList:
    """Represent a collection of tasks that 
    can be searched, modified and complete and deleted """

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []
```

The `__init__` doesn't get called (because of a typo) and the `tasks` attribute never gets created.